# Setting up Debian server for remote backups

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, rsync

I am running a Debian Wheezy server at home, and am offering an organization to let them do `rsync` backups to their own folder on my system. I created the unique user for them, and got a strong password. I will eventually give them a public key to use instead, and then disable password log in. That's for the future.

The default shell is `/bin/false`, as I don't want them doing other things on the server. I tried to run an `rsync` to the server, type the password in - Then the session is disconnected immediately. I get the same error when I use WinSCP to test the connection. I can `su -s /bin/bash USERNAME` from the Super User to the regular user, so I know that works.

**What can I change to allow this user to log in via an SSH connection for the sole purpose of running an `rsync` from their Debian server to this one?**

Comment: Related (and fixed!): http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15695363#15695363

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to give the user a shell. You can use `rssh` which is a restricted shell allowing only scp, rsync an other similar commands.